# Remove entry enable/disable for user

Tags: users, control-panel

Is there a way to disable the general entry enable/disable toggle button for some users and let them have only the localised enable/disable button.
Because I had the problem that a user disabled an entry with the general button and he disabled the entry for all locales. So I want to make it easier for them and remove that general button that affects others.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to use the [Control Panel CSS plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) and hide the button with CSS. But I guess that would hide it for all users, including admins.
Maybe you could write a little plugin for it that checks who logs into the CP and hide it if it's a certain user(group).

Answer (score 1):

As Tom mentioned, you can use the Control Panel CSS plugin alongside [this CP Body Classes plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpbodyclasses), also by the same great dev. Basically it will add user group classes to the `body`.